# How much does it cost to land on a lunar mascon?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, gravity, mascon

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43215/12102) to *Delta-v for landing on the moon* estimates that to go from a circular orbit at 110km to a landing on a spherical Moon would require an absolute minimum of 1736 m/s and the Apollo landers budgeted about 20% more for more realistic landings.

25 m/s is used to change the circular orbit into an elliptical orbit which intersects the surface, and the rest at the last moments in a "suicide burn" to reduce velocity to zero on touchdown.

---

Suppose I wanted to land on top of the most challenging [lunar mass concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(astronomy)) or mascon. *Over time,* mascons have brought spacecraft crashing into the Moon because their locally higher gravity fields perturbs their orbits, making them more eccentric until they intercept the surface. Their effect is a little bit like small, inward-pointing radial impulses discussed in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43262/12102).

[image: radial impulse to a circular orbit]

**Question:** It it possible to *roughly estimate* based on the sizes and strengths of lunar mascons what the delta-v penalty would be for safely landing on, or just past (downrange) of the biggest lunar mascon? Would it for example require an additional 1 or 10 or 100 m/s to counteract the higher local gravity?

**fyi:** I've just asked [How can I make a Python function return the Moon's gravitational force in a form I can use to calculate orbits?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/19566/6031) in Earth Science SE, if there's anything helpful I'll update here.

I also wonder if there is a faulty premise in my question. Could a carefully choreographed orbit use several passes (over time) to use the mascon in a constructive way to do some of the work of that 25 m/s transfer to the surface-intersecting elliptical orbit? Would it in fact require less delta-v than to land elsewhere somehow?

[image: These maps of the moon show gravity anomalies measured by NASA's GRAIL mission. (Image credit: NASA/JPL-Caltech/CSM)]

> These maps of the moon show gravity anomalies measured by NASA's GRAIL mission. (Image credit: NASA/JPL-Caltech/CSM)

From Space.com's [Mystery of Moon's Lumpy Gravity Explained](https://www.space.com/21364-moon-gravity-mascons-mystery.html), click for full size.

The [Bouguer anomaly plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouguer_anomaly) show elevated gravity as much as about 600 mGal. Wikipedia's [Gal (unit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gal_(unit)) explains what this means; 0.6 Gal is 0.006 m/s^2 or almost a half of a percent of the Moon's average gravity, and they extend over quite large distances.

> The gal (symbol: Gal), sometimes called galileo after Galileo Galilei, is a unit of acceleration used extensively in the science of gravimetry. The gal is defined as 1 centimeter per second squared (1 cm/s2). The milligal (mGal) and microgal (µGal) are respectively one thousandth and one millionth of a gal.

Comment: different but related: [How much harder is it to land on the Moon away from the equator and the poles?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9711/12102)

Comment: Please notice that the gravitatory field from mascons is tiny compared to the overall gravitatory field of the Moon. They perturb orbits in the long term but their effect on a single orbit is small. Therefore, landing on a mascon is not going to be very different than landing on a different point of the Moon under the same orbit.

Comment: @Pere that's right, I've mentioned that it's about a half of a percent. Whether you call half of a percent "large" or "small", the effect on a trajectory can still be calculated.